# Need restrictions to fully prevent connecting both LAN and WIFI

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, group-policy

I there a way to fully prevent bypassing WIFI and Ethernet to be connected on the same time

This will be a way for professional user to connect to internet in restricted area

I found a solution in Group Policy to prevent such connection
"Prohibit connection to non-domain networks when connected to domain authenticated network"

Can this policy **fully** prevent such behavior

Answer (score 1):

The Group Policy
[Prohibit connection to non-domain networks when connected to domain authenticated network](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-windowsconnectionmanager)
is described as doing what you wish for.

However, in the post
[Windows 10 WiFi and Corporate network](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/258756f7-9677-46d4-aa58-ddb4f0ba78b1/windows-10-wifi-and-corporate-network?forum=winserverGP)
it is remarked that this policy does not work as expected when enabled.
At least in 2019, it was remarked that it's better to disable the policy
and enable it via the registry at
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WcmSvc\GroupPolicy\fBlockNonDomain`.
Set it to `1` to disable simultaneous connections to both Non-domain and
Domain networks.

You will need to experiment, to see if this group policy works as expected
in your Windows 10 version.

More information:
[Disable Simultaneous Connection to Non-domain and Domain in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/disable-simultaneous-connection-to-non-domain-and-domain-in-windows-10/).

Comment: So a user with IT skill can enable this from registry, Is there a solution on how to enforce this to all users

Comment: The HKLM registry applies to all users, as does the group policy. Using `regedit` requires Administrator permissions, and  a user with those permissions cannot be blocked from doing anything.